# How to express $r$ in $\phi$ with equation $r \cos(\phi) + r^2\sin(\phi) = 2$?

Tags: polar-coordinates

If we convert an equation in Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates, can we always represent one variable by the rest?

Comment: The equation is a quadratic in $r$. Invert it using the standard techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x=r \cos\phi;\;y=r\sin\phi$

$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

The equations can be written as

$r\cos\phi+ r(r\sin\phi)=2$ and then

$x+y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

This is a quadratic equation in $r$, waiting for you to solve it.